why do we need dedicated servers and clients even if most of the protocols can be done through web servers and clients
Why do we need different architecture for different application layer protocols (telnet, FTP etc), even if most of the protocols can be done through web servers and clients? Like web based ssh, web based email ?
Before the conceptualization and invention of web, i can understand that the application protocols had their own different architectures like telnet , ftp etc...
But after the creation of http and urls can't we just use web servers and clients for all of other protocols, we would probably have to register other protocols as URI schemes ( there is wikipedia entry on this list ), and then just like ftp we can use other application layer protocols using web servers too.
But still we have dedicated servers for other application layer protocols, why is it so ?
i honestly searched google with the best queries i could come up with, but wasn't able to find any relevant article or books. I tried asking chatgpt, but it gave very vague kind of answers.

Related reading: When webservers send a page, why don't they send all required CSS, JS, and images without being asked?

@StephenOstermiller that question was helpful.... i didn't knew tim berners lee never consulted professionals, maybe it was a deliberate choice, i mean afterall he certainly would have known what was he doing..... but i just didn't knew..

Just another thought to add to Stephen and Maximillian's great input., we don't optimize every server/protocol alike.  For instance, database servers aren't optimized the same way as we optimize file servers, or web servers.  Some are more CPU intensive, where others are more ram intensive.  Using a file transfer protocol (like HTTP) for a database call would be extremely inefficient, so database servers have their own protocols that are better for transferring large recordsets of data.

@Trebor helpful comment indeed, thanks...

Web servers and clients are a bit different than protocols. Are you asking why everything on the internet doesn't run on browser-first protocols like HTTP requests and websockets?
If so, the answer is that they can be inefficient at transferring certain types of data, and their complex spec is overkill for simple tasks. You could imagine how a websocket might guzzle bandwidth and do a poor job at keeping a real-time game in sync, or how trying to do an ICMP request over HTTP/3 would require an embedded system to have half a web browser implemented in it, or how simply needing to negotiate a TLS key exchange for every connection (required by HTTP/3) could make certain applications infeasible. On the other hand if you use HTTP/1.1 because it doesn't come with TLS built in, then that comes with its own set of inefficiencies arising from the ancient specification.
In the case of security-critical apps like SSH, having a dedicated protocol is also beneficial for reducing attack surface. TLS isn't even really compatible with the style of key authentication used by SSH, so if SSH were performed over HTTP/3, then the stream would need to be doubly encrypted with one of the layers of encryption being useless: once by TLS and once by the chosen SSH algorithm. It's better to have no unnecessary moving parts.
IMO, it's important to ask the reverse question. Why would you restrict yourself to only creating subprotocols of HTTP, when you could just create a new application-layer protocol instead and sidestep the complexity and bloat (and wasted bandwidth) of trying to encapsulate everything you do into HTTP streams?

" Web servers and clients are a bit different than protocols. Are you asking why everything on the internet doesn't run on browser-first protocols like HTTP requests and websockets?  "  -   What i meant was that the web has a particular architecture - server-client in simple words. And many ( if not  all ) application layer protocols too have this client-server architecture implementation.  - ( contd. )

And there are like more than 50 URI schemes including ftp, tel, telnet, ssh etc , there's a wikipedia page on the list. So i assume all of those can be used or implemented using web server client model, afterall these uri schems are to be used in urls...  So why do we still need dedicated servers for many protocols including ssh, email, telnet etc...  is this like a trade-off thing, where if you want you can implement pretty much any application layer protocol using web server-client model, but sometimes there are circumstances where web architecture provides really bad performance

I'm still not sure I fully understand. To be clear, which specific application layer web protocols are you imagining that ftp/telnet/ssh would be subprotocols of? When you say "implemented using a web server client model", I can only assume you mean "as a subprotocol of a specific protocol that web servers/clients typically use to communicate with each other", which is for the most part HTTP and Websocket. Otherwise you're just e.g. bundling a standard FTP client with your web server and web browser (which was the case for a long time before FTP was deprecated from major browsers).

your answer does answers my question, but at the moment i would still like to read other opinions, if any, maybe mention of good articles etc.... so i'm just waiting for replies, for next couple of days...

" To be clear, which specific application layer web protocols are you imagining that ftp/telnet/ssh would be subprotocols of? "  -  No no no...  i am not talking in terms of sub-protocols at all. There are uri schmes, and http, ftp etc, all are registered uri schemes, so whatever algorithm we use to make a web browse and server, we can use http, as well as ftp and many other as uri shchmes right ?..... there is no need or concept of sub-protocols over here....  and upon this stands my question, if we can use most of the protocols as uri schmes, why do need dedicated architectures then....

We need some sort of dedicated architecture because e.g. maintaining a terminal session (SSH) has much different requirements than the typical web server's use case of serving up web pages. For instance, with SSH, the server software needs to be able to receive a stream of input, write text to a remote terminal, and execute the user's commands.

So, if you imagine writing a web server that does support this specialized functionality - you'd have to come up with a protocol for how the client sends this specialized data and how the server receives and interprets it. This new SSH-like protocol has to either be a sub-protocol of HTTP/Websocket (and thus carry overhead that may not be necessary to the protocol's functioning), or NOT a sub-protocol of HTTP/Websocket (a separate protocol unrelated to web server protocols, the current status quo like SSH already is.) If the latter, then you're just bundling an SSH server with your web server.

ok, so like web based ssh is a sub-protocol, it uses ajax or web sockets... is that what you're saying ?.....

Yes, exactly. If by "web-based ssh" you mean an SSH-like protocol that gets carried by (is encapsulated by) traditional web protocols, then those traditional web protocols would be HTTP (which includes AJAX), and perhaps WebSockets. If the SSH-like protocol gets carried over those protocols, that would make it a sub-protocol of those protocols.

i am afraid now i have another confusion, so apparently ssh is also a uri scheme,  and its also used as sub protocol by the name 'web based ssh', are they both different things or the same ?

In your original question, you mentioned "web-based ssh" as a hypothetical alternative to the way SSH currently works. But I get what you're saying now: "web-based ssh" is a real thing that exists and is actually carried over ajax (http) or websockets.

The reasons web-based ssh is not commonly used (and that I didn't even know about it) probably come down to using additional overhead and requiring additional, potentially more fragile software/configuration to get working. This is in contrast to standard SSH, where I can install and configure an SSH server once using a simple config file, and I can be reasonably sure that it will stay secure and accessible for many years as long as it gets patched for CVEs. It has a smaller attack surface than web server software.

I wonder if you are confusing / merging the Transport, Session and Presentation layer of the standard OSI model.  (If you are not familiar with the 7 layer OSI model, you should look  it up - understanding it will likely answer your question)
For the most part, the URL is an addressing scheme, and that has largely been standardized - although not all protocols see a need for the complexity parsing this.  (This would be part of the presentation layer).
The Session layer is where things get quite interesting.  Historically the web used TCP - and this protocol is great for certain types of communication, but not others - particularly its not good for real-time traffic where if a packet does not arrive quickly enough it should be ignored.   [ As an aside, QUIC - a newer web protocol uses UDP, but adds requirements suitable to web on top of it ].   If you think about gaming and live streaming the protocols of the web don't work well.
Additionally there are other - lower level/hybrid/intermediate protocols like those used for VPN's - and the requirements to set up a VPN do not necessarily fit neatly into a URL schema.   There are also protocols (for example SIP, torrent protocols) which do not neatly fit the client/server model of the web.
While FTP is a horrible, horrible protocol that needed to die a long time ago telnet is actually an extremely simple protocol - indeed it is almost a lower level protocol then HTTP (let alone HTTPS).   Telnet is just a little more then a raw tcp session - to the point you can easily talk HTTP in it.
Things like web based SSH and web based email are again something different - where you are almost abusing the web to act as a kind of proxy/interface to those protocols.   In the case of Webmail, the webmail program is an email program that renders its output for the web.   In the case of SSH, its really doing something similar but harder - and to some extent compromising the security of the SSH client as well.
